# Sqllite database updated rows become last row of database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

My database table consists of many rows where unique key is the id for which I'm using unique identifier. So no duplicate items are there.

I am using `replace()` method to add items to database so that if any column is updated then it is replaced by new value. But the issue is that suppose my first row of database is updated then it will become the last row with the updated value.Also i don't know which column of row will be updated as the data is coming from server..

If i use `insert()` method in place of `replace()` for adding items then items will not be  updated.What should I do so that my rows are also replaced and the order of items should not be changed after update.

Code-

```
 String CREATE_VIDEO_TABLE = "create table "
                + TABLE_VIDEO + "(" + KEY_ID + " text not null unique, "
                + KEY_CAPTION + " text not null, "
                + KEY_LOCATION + " text not null, "
                + KEY_NOSHARES + 
                 " text not null);";


      public void addVideoData(Video videoSql) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_ID, videoSql.getId());
            values.put(KEY_CAPTION, videoSql.getCaption());
            values.put(KEY_LOCATION, videoSql.getLocation());
            values.put(KEY_NOSHARES, videoSql.getNoOfShares());

            try {
                db.replace(TABLE_VIDEO, null, values);
            }catch(Exception e){}

            db.close();
        }
```

Comment: You need something like `update()` ?

Comment: @user1354678 But i can't use update..i don't know which column of row will be updated as the data is coming from server

Comment: Then how do you know which row gets replaced?

Comment: main problem is how is PK in your table defined... if it is not a INTEGER then ROWID will be changed on replace

Comment: @CL I don't know which rows get updated..check out in question...i have posted code..while addind data i am using replace() method..

Comment: Check out in question..i have posted code..

Comment: type of PK is important ... still i don't get where is the problem ... if you are not using ROWID then there should be no problem ... define KEY_ID  as PK

Comment: @Selvin The issue with above code posted in question is that suppose my first row of database is replaced then it will become the last row with the updated value

Comment: because by default it is ordered by ROWID ... if you don't need it order it by ... i dont know ... creation date ...

Comment: @Selvin But i want that if any row suppose first row is updated..then after updation also it should remain first row only..it should not become last row after updation

Comment: THATS HOW REPLACE WORKS WITHOUT OWN INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IN SQLITE

Comment: @Selvin Why my updated row become the last row of table..any idea?currently i am not ordering it by anything..i am fresher in android so taking time to understand..

Comment: ok again: THATS HOW REPLACE WORKS WITHOUT OWN INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IN SQLITE .... IT USES ROWID COLUMN AND IT CAN BE CHANGED ON REPLACE ... [change](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/00eb9/1) ... [no change](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/126e9/1) ...

Comment: @Selvin Thanku for ur time..but i am not using any PRIMARY KEY in my database table..where am i going wrong if thats how REPLACE works?

Comment: @Selvin I am not using any PRIMARY KEY in my database.My list displays list of images and data coming from server..For offline caching purpose i am storing data in sqllite.But suppose i update a data item when i am online then when i'll load data offline it will become the last item

Answer (score 2):

If you have created your updateRow method right way then it won't add an updated row at the last but it will replace it rather and won't change the `id` either.

To update Db your method should be like,

```
public void updateRow(int id ,String name, String address, String date){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_ID, id);
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, name);
    values.put(COLUMN_ADDRESS, address);
    values.put(COLUMN_DATE, date);

    db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, COLUMN_ID+ " = " +id, null);
    db.close();
}
```

**Edit:**

You don't need to use `replace()` method in your case, use `update()` method. This will not put updated row at the last, and will also keep the `id` same.

Change

```
try {
            db.replace(TABLE_VIDEO, null, values);
        }catch(Exception e){}
```

To

```
db.update(TABLE_VIDEO, values, KEY_ID+ " = " +videoSql.getId(), null);
```

If you use this same method (the method you have posted in question) to insert data and update data it will always put your row at last, you need to create one another method to insert data in database. It should be as follow.

```
public void insertData(Video videoSql){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_CAPTION, videoSql.getCaption());
    values.put(KEY_LOCATION, videoSql.getLocation());
    values.put(KEY_NOSHARES, videoSql.getNoOfShares());
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .

    db.insert(TABLE_VIDEO, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: i don't know which column of row will be updated as the data is coming from server..Check out in question..i have posted code..

Comment: but suppose when first time i am inserting particular data item to table then i can't use update..in my case data is coming from server and the data item might already be there in database or it might be also new to database..

Comment: @user3684678 then you need to create one another method for data insertion, you cannot use same method to insert and update data. Create both. I think you haven't tried any tutorial yet. Okay, I am editing my answer to show you how to insert data.

Comment: I know how to insert data to database table..i think u are not getting my issue..check out in comments posted on question

Comment: @user3684678 hundreds of people I know use separate methods to insert and update data. You are the first person with replace method! I suggested what you should do, if you don't do you then sacrifice with updated row at last.

Comment: my data is coming from server which i am using from caching..i don't know whether a particular data item is already there in table or need to be inserted for first time..and if i want to know that than i have to run a loop to check whether item is already there in table..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use update(table_name, contentValues, where clause, bind parameters), pass the id as where clause, and must work

Comment: i don't know which column of row will be updated as the data is coming from server..Check out in question..i have posted code..

Comment: @user3684678, If you dont know row will be updated, then how will `replace()` supposed to work.